# Fhir server - register custom extension

Tags: dstu2-fhir, hl7-fhir

the way I understand extension is that , it's a structure where you can keep attributes which are not listed in the fhir specification. We are also supposed to explain that extension via 'URL' and 'System' property.

We can create pages in our fhir server using ASP.NET MVC. Should we follow any format / guide lines about that page design ? Also , do we have any tool which will create the page and publish it ?

Answer (score 1):

To create new StructureDefinitions for both extensions and constraints, you could take a look at the [Forge](http://fhir.furore.com/Forge) tool. This tool can publish your definition to your own server, or to the [Simplifier.net](https://simplifier.net/) registry, which will display your definitions nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Extensions are defined using the StructureDefinition resource.  Ideally, the cannonical URL for the extension should resolve to the StructureDefinition that defines the extension, though you can also meet the requirement by sharing the StructureDefinition with potential consumers of instances that reference that extension or by posting the StructureDefinition instance to a registry that instance consumers will be familiar with.  So there aren't any pages to design per se . . .